# How to use [(ngModel)] and innerHTML on div's contenteditable in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular8

Here's my code :

```
<div #editor class="editor" 
              style=" max-height: 200px;" 
              (input)="onChange()"
              [(ngModel)]="blogData.description"
              name="description"
              contenteditable></div>
```

The Error that i am getting:

```
Error: No value accessor for form control with name: 'description'
```

How can i use [(ngModel)] as well as innerHTML property on div's contenteditable?

Answer (score 4):

You need to write your own `ControlValueAccessor` to work with contenteditable:
https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

I already did it and released it as opensource package, feel free to use it:
https://github.com/TinkoffCreditSystems/angular-contenteditable-accessor
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@tinkoff/angular-contenteditable-accessor

It works with all modern browsers, including IE11.